# Why can't svg scale to fit child elements?

Tags: javascript, svg

I would an svg element which could scale to fit its children elements. Say you have:

```
<svg> 
  <rect width=10 height=1000/>
<svg>
```

It seems like there would be a way to get the svg to scale to fit the rectangle inside of it.

Unfortunately, it appears such a thing is impossible, at least according to this:

[SVG Fill Width to Child Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452610/svg-fill-width-to-child-elements)

Can anyone give me an explanation as to why this cannot be acheived? It seems like this would be a highly requested feature... or maybe I'm just not getting something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A special `viewBox` value of `"auto"` has been discussed for inclusion in the specification for SVG 2, which is still under development.

If it makes the final specification, this would do what you are suggesting.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the info. So, just to double check, the proposed viewBox: "auto" would allow the svg container to grow to fit its contents?

Comment: Yes.  It would be set to the union of the bounding boxes of all the child elements.